# Turn off Authentication in MVC using web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have an MVC site, secured using [Authorize] attributes, but have an issue on a production website that uses Single Sign On accross a couple or sites on different servers. I want to rule Authentication out as the cause; is there a way to temporarily turn off the Authentication through web.config so that all or some Controller Actions that have the Authorize Attribute can be accessed without logging in?

EDIT:

I have tried adding the following to web.config:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

But this causes all actions decorated with Authorize Attribute to render blank pages.  Actions without Authorize continue to work though

Comment: I love it. I just searched for: asp.net authentication none blank page, and found this question. My problem was that I had authorization set to none but accidentally had leftover Authorize statements in one of my controllers. Your question was my answer. Thanks!

Comment: And that is why I love stack overflow :) Glad it helped - it certianly had me scratching my head when I first hit it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there a way to temporarily turn off the Authentication through
>   web.config so that all or some Controller Actions that have the
>   Authorize Attribute can be accessed without logging in?

No, this is not possible with the default framework.  I'm pretty sure the `AuthorizeAttribute` in MVC source code will attempt to check and see if the user is logged in.  Without an authenticated user, access would be denied.

Answer (score 9):

Use [AllowAnonymous] to allow specific actions in a controller be used by unauthorized users.

Answer (score 1):

In your Web.config comment out the  child:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <!--<deny users="?" />-->
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow all users access to the system by adding the following in the web.config. When the controller checks the authorization the user will be verified since you are letting all users with any windows authentication access the system.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
  <!--<deny users="?" />-->
    </authorization>
```