# How trurn on/off authrization of a controller based on some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, owin

We have an requirement to turn on/off authorization attribute based on some configuration and requirement by different sites. For starters let's say , the configuration comes from config file.

I tried creating a custom attribute and applying that to controller, but none of the over rides gets called. So really can't do anything on this pipeline.

```
public class ConditionalAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            return false;

        }

    }
```

Is there another way?

Comment: If `web.config` is an option then [Turn off Authentication in MVC using web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880154/turn-off-authentication-in-mvc-using-web-config) thread would help else you can always `allow/block` users based on some condition in the `OnAuthorization()` method.

Comment: could you put in the code for the controller you're applying the `ConditionalAuthorizationAttribute` to?

Comment: @BlackICE,  I was applying Authorize attribute at controller level and replaced that with ConditionalAuthorization , eg: [ConditionalAuthorization]  public class MyController : Controller
 {....}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version you are using, but with the following

```
 public class ConditionalAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public static bool FlipFlop = true;
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            FlipFlop = !FlipFlop;
            return FlipFlop;
        }
}
```

and

```
 [ConditionalAuthorization]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

it will alternate between auth and not auth

Comment: I am MVC5 not the core, so do not have override bool AuthorizeCore

Comment: And  , do I need to register this attribute any where before start using it?